# Enable ssl to docker nginx container

Tags: php, docker, ssl, nginx, docker-compose

I'm trying to enable SSL on my local nginx docker container.
I try to change my Dockerfile:

```
# install openssl
RUN apk add --no-cache openssl

# create a folder for the keys
RUN mkdir /etc/nginx/ssl 2> /dev/null

# generate the keys for your local domain
RUN openssl genrsa -out "/etc/nginx/ssl/YOURLOCALDOMAIN.key" 2048 \
&& openssl req -new -key "/etc/nginx/ssl/YOURLOCALDOMAIN.key" -out "/etc/nginx/ssl/YOURLOCALDOMAIN.csr" -subj "/CN=YOURLOCALDOMAIN/O=YOURCOMPANYNAME/C=UK" \
&& openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in "/etc/nginx/ssl/YOURLOCALDOMAIN.csr" -signkey "/etc/nginx/ssl/YOURLOCALDOMAIN.key" -out "/etc/nginx/ssl/YOURLOCALDOMAIN.crt"
```

And my website config file:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl;
listen [::]:80;
server_name {SITE_NAME};
root /var/www/{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

ssl_certificate     {CERTIFICATE_LOCATION};
ssl_certificate_key {KEY_LOCATION};

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
}
```

After I tried to run

> docker-compose build --force-rm --no-cache nginx

But on my log file I have this error:

> BIO_new_file("/etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.local.crt") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.local.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)

Do you know how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: seems like file in `/etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.local.crt` doesnt exist